# What's the Difference Between 吹风 and 刮风?

Tags: word-choice, mandarin, synonyms

In both word choice, and use, what is the difference between 吹风 and 刮风? Can I say "今天刮风很大“ but not say ”今天吹风很大“？

Comment: iciba: 吹风 be in a draught; catch a chill; dry one's hair; dry hair with a blower, 刮风: wind blowing. More details at iciba.

Comment: both are possible（with some correction), cf .＂汉语３８０动词＂吹／夸。一、吹１。他把蜡烛吹灭了。动词＂吹＂是把嘴春合拢后用力出气的意思。如～气、～火、～灰尘等。＂吹＂还表示用嘴吹乐器或曲调等。如～笛、～喇叭、～口哨、～曲子等。２。地上的树叶被吹跑了。＂吹＂在这儿的意思是因风或气流等流动而产生某种冲击力量。如～风，～电扇，～头发等。

users would suggest 风刮／吹得很大 instead

Comment: some users would suggest replacing 大 by 厉害 in preceding comment: 风刮／吹得很厉害, however find many examples with 风刮得很大 at jukuu (also correct 3rd character in 2nd line to 唇 and insert 奏 between 吹 and 乐器）

Comment: 今天风很大, you should not use 刮风 or 吹风 in this example. 吹风 has specific meaning. for example, it means you reveal something to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

吹风 is defined by Oxfford as:

> VERB
>
> 1 让风吹 get a blast of air

One of the most common usages of this is when people are on motorcycles because the 风 is constantly 吹ing the rider and passengers.

Oxford also gives the example sentence:

> 你感冒了, 不要吹风。
>
> You've got a cold. Don't go getting yourself caught in a draught.

You can also common 吹风 with air conditioning and electric fans too.

刮风 is defined by ABC as:

> V.O.
>
> 1 the wind blows

and here are two sample sentences from Liang'an:

> 颳風了, 關窗戶吧

Close the window, it's getting windy.

> 颳風下雨。

rainy and windy.

Answer (score 1):

"今天吹风很大" is a wrong sentence, which should be replaced with "今天刮风很大".

According to Baidu Dictionary([the interpretations from baidu dictionary](http://dict.baidu.com/s?wd=%E5%90%B9%E9%A3%8E&ab=12))the term "吹风" has following meaning:

1) makes gas through some instrument.

2) let wind blow

3) use blower to dry one's hair

4) let somebody know something in advance

However, the term "刮风" has absolutely different meaning from term "吹风" because it describes as a natural phenomenon, i.e. the horizontal component motion of the air. (According to [Baidu Encyclopedia](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=9I2mB47Cyy8yTs1wvkq0BVCoVAmaTLT7RLpCX83JOdJc7fA2ca1X8wb8ek_9b8rsEiPVKlfSl37ZDasF1a8P2Es6MVbLN0CluUU015sAIVm)!)

Answer (score 0):

"今天吹风很大" is wrong, and "今天刮风很大" sounds weird.

To talk about weather, usually we say "今天风很大", "今天刮大风". We never use "吹风" for weather.

Actually usage of "吹风" is weird by itself.